# Can we create a category list page in WordPress?

Tags: plugin-development, categories

I am working on a category. I have to show all the category list on-page. So I tried the below code and it's working. I am getting my all the category list.

**Below is the output of my category list**

[image]

My question is, Where I go and add the category list code?
I have to access the URL like `http://test.com/category/` so it will display my category list.

I created the `category.php` page but that page is displaying the post with the related category.

For example `http://test.com/category/destination` so it will display all the post which is related to the destination.

```
<?php
   /**
   * A Simple Category Template
   */
   get_header(); 

?>  
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
   <main id="main" class="site-main">
       <div class="CategoryHero">
<?php
// Get the current queried object
$term    = get_queried_object();
$term_id = ( isset( $term->term_id ) ) ? (int) $term->term_id : 0;

$categories = get_categories( array(
    'taxonomy'   => 'category',
    'orderby'    => 'name',
    'parent'     => 0,
    'hide_empty' => 0, // change to 1 to hide categores not having a single post
) );
?>

<ul>
    <?php
    foreach ( $categories as $category ) 
    {
        $cat_ID        = (int) $category->term_id;
        $category_name = $category->name;

        // When viewing a particular category, give it an [active] class
        $cat_class = ( $cat_ID == $term_id ) ? 'active' : 'not-active';

        // I don't like showing the [uncategoirzed] category
        if ( strtolower( $category_name ) != 'uncategorized' )
        {
            printf('<li><a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ) . '">' . $category->name . '</a></li>');
        }
    }
    ?>
</ul>
     
         </div>
   </main>
</div>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**Second page**

The output of below code is

```
Africa
--Post one
--Post two
```

//

```
<?php
   /**
   * A Simple Category Template
   */
   get_header(); 

?>  
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
   <main id="main" class="site-main">
       <div class="CategoryHero">
           
     <?php 
    if (have_posts()){
        if(is_category()){                   
                 $category_images = get_option( 'category_images' );
                 $category_image = '';
                 if ( is_array( $category_images ) && array_key_exists( get_query_var('cat'), $category_images ) ){
                  $category_image = $category_images[get_query_var('cat')] ;
                 ?>        
                  <div class="category-img" style="background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)),url(<?php echo $category_image;?>)">
                      <div class="container h-100">
                      <div class="categoryWrapper">
                    <div class="categoryContent">
                        <h1><?php single_cat_title(''); ?></h1>
                        <p><?php echo category_description(); ?></p>
                        </div>
                        
                        </div>
                        </div>
                      
                      </div>
                 <?php
                 }
                 }?>
           <div class="categoryWrapper_list"><div class="equalPadding"><ul>
         <?php  
             
        while (have_posts()) {
            the_post();
            ?>
           <li> <div class="subCategoryPostWrap" style="background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)),url(<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $_post->ID, 'thumbnail' );?>)">

                    <div class="productContent colcentertext">
                        
                <div class="blackBoxPackage">
                    <div class="cp-b-content">
                        <h4><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_title(), 15, '...');?></h4>
             <p><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_excerpt(), 30, '...');?></p>
          <div class="canExplore"><a class="canbtn" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_the_permalink() );?>">Explore now</a></div>
          </div>

        
                    
        </div>
        
    </div>  
    </div></li><?php }?></ul>
              <div class="pt-5 text-center"><a class="canbtn cabbtnbg canbtnPadding removeArrowbtn loadMore" href="javascript:void(0);">Load More Packages</a></div>

    </div>
    
</div>
<?php } else{?><p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p><?php } ?>
         </div>
   </main>
</div>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: @fuxia, Any help in this?

Comment: The `category.php` template is used to render any category. This is the default "detail page" of your categories. So what you did there is that on every category page, you show the list of your destinations. Is that what you intended to do? If you want to fetch all the posts linked to the current category you can use `get_posts(['category'=>$term_id]);` and then loop on them.

Comment: @Tim, What I am doing is, I have to display all categories on my page then when users click on any category then it will redirect on that category page and it will display the post related to the category.

Comment: @Tim, So, I have both code. I mean, To display the list of category and click on category to display the related post. I am little bit confused. Do I need to combine both codes and add them to the cateory.php page? or else I have to create 2 pages for first displaying the category list and the second to display the category related post

Comment: Depends on your needs, if you want to have a single page showing (A) the term and all its posts; AND (B) every other terms in a list; you'll have to combine both codes. I don't think that there is a "single term" template, you might need put everything in the same (not sure though).

Comment: @Tim, I added my second-page code. I mean I added both page code in the question. My need is, All category list--if click any category--display  post related to that category