# Category images are not displaying in WordPress

Tags: categories, images, post-thumbnails

I have categories list with there respective images. I am able to get the category name and description but I am not getting the category image. I tried the below code.

```
    <ul>
      <?php
        $categories = get_categories( array(
            'taxonomy'   => 'category',
            'orderby'    => 'name',
            'parent'     => 0,
            'hide_empty' => 0, 
        ) );
        
            foreach ( $categories as $category ) 
            {
            $cat_ID        = $category->term_id;
            $category_name = $category->name;
            $category_desc = $category->description;
            //$category_img = $category->category_images;
            //$category_images = get_option('category_images');?>

           <li>
           <?php
           echo $category_name;
           echo $category_desc;
           echo $category_images; //display the path of image for temporary

              $category_images = get_option('category_images');
        
?>       
   </li>
          <?php } ?>
        </ul>
```

I am getting the `var_dump($category_images)` output

```
array(9) {
  [17]=>
  string(0) ""
  [18]=>
  string(63) "http://test.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/reghwij.png"
  [19]=>
  string(63) "http://test.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/hgeioiq.jpg"
  [21]=>
  string(88) "http://test.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/dan-freeman-m4-wkz4GV04-unsplash.png"
  [22]=>
  string(68) "http://test.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/green-breaks.jpg"

}
```

var_dump($category) Output

[image]

Comment: WordPress doesn’t support images for categories out of the box. Are you using a plug-in? Or is this a feature of your theme

Comment: @JacobPeattie, No I am not using any plugin. I added custom code in the function to add the image. you can refer this link https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/352455/how-to-add-a-background-image-to-category-and-display-image-on-category-page

Comment: @JacobPeattie, After adding the code in the function I got an image upload option in the category page and I am able to add it and edit it. Now I have to show all the images on my category list page https://prnt.sc/tv26ee and this https://prnt.sc/tv282i

Comment: @JacobPeattie, I added the var_dump($category) output (only one) in the question

Comment: I tried the above code and I am getting every time first image.

Comment: I solved the issue using $category_images[$cat_ID];

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you store the images in the `wp_options` table with the key `category_images`, but there is nothing that tells WordPress that it must fetch the image when loading the taxonomy term (your category).

What you can do is either use `get_option('category_images')` whenever you need to fetch the image, or add a hook filter like that.

```
add_filter( 'get_term', function ( WP_Term $_term, string $taxonomy ): WP_Term
{
    if ( 'my_taxonomy_name' === $taxonomy ) {
        $images = get_option( 'category_images' );
        if ( $image = ( $images[ $_term->term_id ] ?? null ) ) {
            $_term->background_image = $image;
        }
    }
    
    return $_term;
}, 10, 2 );
```

You will then have the `background_image` property added when you fetch your taxonomy term.

Comment: Sure I will try your answer, I updated my code also, Can you check it. I am getting the first image every time.

Comment: I have to add this code in function.php?

Comment: I'll have to double check that. You can store only one image for every term. What is the first image that you always get?

Comment: I was getting the first one. After adding this $category_images[$cat_ID]; my issue got solved.

Comment: Didn't you use this : $image = $images[ $_term->term_id ]. As in my answer?

Comment: I was confused about where I have to use your code. So I tried some more time and I got solution

Comment: Usually you can either create a plugin or add that kind of code in your functions file.

Comment: I got your point.

Comment: Can you help me in this issue https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/372465/can-we-create-a-category-list-page-in-wordpress